# For Facebook Marketing API Basic and Standard access, can the cap for number of custom audiences be increased?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

We are building an internal tool that will buy Facebook Ads programmatically - focusing mainly on email-based custom audiences.

We will be building/associating one custom audience for each ad set that we create.

We estimate that we will need **more** than 500 custom audiences. We are currently on the **developer** access level, and will be applying for Basic access soon.

For now Facebook states that *only 500 custom audiences* can be created https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-targeting/v2.3

Will the cap on number of custom audiences be increased as you progress to the **Basic or Standard access levels?** Have you been authorized to create **more than 500** custom audiences for a given account?

Comment: That limit isn't based on access level, it's a hard limit for all accounts - you'll need to spread the audiences across multiple accounts otherwise

Comment: Thanks for your reply - we will probably have to go about doing what you mentioned. Is it possible to request for an increase in custom audiences? Is that something your team allows for? This will simplify things on our side. Thanks again!

Comment: No, there's no whitelist or other access-based limits, the same limits apply to all accounts regardless of which, if any, apps manage those accounts